# why my gulp+browser-sync settings not work?

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

I have used it for a long time, my settings is [here](https://github.com/hanzichi/jsj/tree/master/gulp-simple), but today I try to start a new project, and use it again, but it does not work as expected.

here is the result when I start the command `gulp`

[image]

my package.json file is the same as before, but with the former downloaded node modules, it can work, with the new downloaded node modules, the result is as above.

why? help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my code from `baseDir: ''` to `baseDir: './'`, and it works